# UWP Combobox Popup Mouseover 3D Visual Editing

Tags: uwp, combobox, controls, uwp-xaml, winui

Trying to remove the weird mousehover or pointerover 3D visual that shows up in my combobox popup.

Just want to change it to a simple color.

I've managed to move the popup, change the background colors, sizes etc...

But the hover animation I can't find.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out which part of the style template does it?

```
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle2" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,0,7"/>
            <Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="504"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>            
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <CarouselPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OverlayOpeningAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.383" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OverlayClosingAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1.0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" KeyTime="0:0:0.216" Value="0.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundDisabled}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundBorderBrushFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocused}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxForegroundFocusedPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForegroundFocusedPressed}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DropDownGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForegroundFocusedPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Popup.VerticalOffset" Value="0"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitOpenThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SplitCloseThemeAnimation ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter" OpenedLength="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OffsetFromCenter="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditableModeStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocused">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocusedOverlayPointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFocusedDropDownBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxFocusedOverlayPressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownGlyph.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxEditableDropDownGlyphForeground}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxFocusedDropDownBackgroundPointerPressed}"/>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Margin" Value="0,3,2,2"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxOverlayPointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxOverlayPressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="DropDownOverlay.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBackgroundPointerPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TextBoxUnfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}" FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxTopHeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ComboBoxThemeMinWidth}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HighlightBackground" Background="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundUnfocused}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxBackgroundBorderBrushUnfocused}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}}" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <TextBox x:Name="EditableText" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource ComboBoxPlaceHolderForeground}}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,0" AutomationProperties.Name="{TemplateBinding AutomationProperties.Name}" Padding="10,3,30,5" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Load="False"/>
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownOverlay" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,2,2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="30" x:Load="False"/>
                            <FontIcon x:Name="DropDownGlyph" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownGlyphForeground}" FontSize="8" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Description}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}" Grid.Row="2" x:Load="False"/>
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" CornerRadius="2" BackgroundSizing="OuterBorderEdge" Background="White" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownBorderBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-1,0,-1" Padding="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownBorderPadding}">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}"/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this: https://edi.wang/post/2018/12/31/how-to-remove-default-fds-effects-in-uwp-apps

I found all I needed to do was add this under the page resources:

```
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlTransparentRevealBackgroundBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlTransparentRevealBorderBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        <Thickness x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushPressed" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushDisabled" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelected" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedUnfocused" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedPressed" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemRevealBorderBrushSelectedDisabled" Color="Transparent" />
```